# Mean Function in R keeps giving me same output despite changing parameters to be calculated

Tags: r, mean

```
 pollutantmean <- function(directory, pollutant, ID = 1:332){
+   files_list <- list.files("specdata", full.names = TRUE)
+   dat <- data.frame()
+   for (i in 1:332){
+     dat <- rbind(dat, read.csv(files_list[i]))
+   }
+   dat_subset <- subset(dat, dat$ID == ID)
+   mean(dat_subset$nitrate, na.rm = TRUE)
+   mean(dat_subset$sulfate, na.rm = TRUE)
+ }
```

> pollutantmean(specdata, sulfate, 1:10)
>   [1] 3.189369
>   pollutantmean(specdata, nitrate, 70:72)
>   [1] 3.189369
>   pollutantmean("specdata", "sulfate", 1:10)
>   [1] 3.189369

Comment: May be change the `==` to `%in%` in `subset`.  Also, do a `print(dat)` to see the dataset you are working

Comment: @akrun The `%in%` would be appropriate in this case, but it turns out that `ID` is being found in `dat`, so the `subset` call is equivalent to `subset(dat, ID == ID)`.  Switching to `%in%` alone won't resolve the issue in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is because the dat does not exisis so we can try:

```
if(exist("dat")== FALSE){
dat <- read.csv(i)
}else{
dat <- rbind(dat, read.csv(files_list[i]))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you are observing is caused by the line

```
dat_subset <- subset(dat, dat$ID == ID)
```

`subset` will look for any variables in the second argument within the first argument.  So when you say `dat$ID == ID`, it looks for `ID` first within `dat`. Since `dat` has an element named `ID`, it is equivalent to saying `dat$ID == dat$ID`. Thus, you aren't actually getting a subset of your data; you're using the complete data set.

To illustrate, let's use the `mtcars` data set.  This data set has 32 rows.  One of the columns is named `am` and his made up of the values `0` and `1` indicating if the vehicle is an automatic or manual transmission

```
nrow(mtcars)
[1] 32
```

Let's define a vector on which to subset `mtcars` on `am`

```
am <- 0
```

When we subset against `am`, we want to get only those rows in `mtcars` where `am == 0`.

```
nrow(subset(mtcars, mtcars$am %in% am))
[1] 32
```

That didn't seem to work, though.  Notice that we get the same result if we use the next line

```
nrow(subset(mtcars, am %in% am))
[1] 32
```

Now let's change the name of our subsetting vector and watch what happens.

```
am_list <- 0
nrow(subset(mtcars, am %in% am_list))
[1] 19
```

In this case, `subset` did not find a column named `am_list` in `mtcars`, so it looked outside of `mtcars` to find an object called `am_list`.  This behavior is one of the reasons behind the warning in `?subset`

> This is a convenience function intended for use interactively. For programming it is better to use the standard subsetting functions like [, and in particular the non-standard evaluation of argument subset can have unanticipated consequences.

I think you would be better off writing your function this way (I took some liberty with rewriting it)

```
pollutantmean <- function(directory, pollutant, ID = 1:332){
  # Get file names from directory argument
  files_list <- list.files(directory, full.names = TRUE)

  # Create a single data frame from all of the files
  dat <- lapply(files_list,
                read.csv)
  dat <- do.call("rbind", dat)

  # Subset the data appropriately
  dat_subset <- dat[dat$ID %in% ID, ]

  # Get the mean of the two columns, return in a list
  lapply(dat_subset[c("nitrate", "sulfate")],
         mean,
         na.rm = TRUE)
}
```